# BooleanField returning "on" instead of True/False

Tags: python, django

I have a boolean field which is returning "on" instead of True/False.

When i print the request.POST queryDict i get something like this:

```
 <QueryDict: {is_superuser': ['on']}>`
```

This is my form:

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    is_superuser = forms.BooleanField(label = 'Superuser', initial = False, required = False)

    class Meta():
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'departments', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_superuser')
        model = get_user_model()

    def clean_is_superuser(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['is_superuser'] == True
```

My view:

```
class SignUpView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', context = {'form':UserCreateForm})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = UserCreateForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit = False)
            user.username = request.POST.get('email')
            user.is_superuser = request.POST.get('is_superuser')
            print(request.POST)
            user.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('accounts:allProfilesPage'))
        return HttpResponse('Form not valid')
```

Why isn't the boolean field passing True or False? I even used the clean data function..

Comment: Why are you using the value for `is_superuser`  from `request.POST` instead of from form? moreover, I don't thin your `clean_is_superuser()` is getting called anywhere....

Comment: You're right! I'm so sorry.. Yesterday i asked a basic question and it was also you who answered me..
 Thanks for being so tolerant.

You're right the "clean" function isn't doing anything.. I just thought that maybe the boolean field was returning some other value instead of False

Answer (score 0):

As @Arakkal Abu already answered:

```
class SignUpView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', context = {'form':UserCreateForm})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = UserCreateForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit = False)
            user.username = form.cleaned_data['email']
            user.is_superuser = form.cleaned_data['is_superuser']

            user.save()

            user.departments.set(form.cleaned_data['departments'])

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('accounts:allProfilesPage'))
        return HttpResponse('Form not valid')
```